Why does the Wheeler-DeWitt equation not describe spin?
In general, when we model particle fields with spin we work out the equations of motion from the Lagrangian and use them to study how the field evolves.
But in the ADM formalism + canonical quantisation, Wheeler and DeWitt simply apply a sort of Schrödinger equation of the form
$$\hat{H}\Psi = 0$$
Where $\Psi$ is said to be the quantum state of the universe.
This comes from the momentum and Hamiltonian constraints, followed by the Dirac canonical quantisation procedure. But my question is, why is this the definite equation? Shouldn’t we work with the field equations next? Why would we have to say
$$\phi_m\Psi = 0$$
for every constraint $\phi_m$ after using Lagrange multipliers to account for the singular Hamiltonian? What would the procedure be if the Hamiltonian were not singular?
